# Cannot pass object to component in Angular using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-components

I am building application using Angular 1.6 component based approach.I have an "article" component which contains a "block" component, and I want to pass data from article to block in ng-repeat loop, but cannot achieve this:
Here is my article template:

```
<md-content class="article-detail">
  <div layout="row">
    <div flex="20"></div>
    <div layout="column" flex="60" layout-align="center center">
      <div class="article-preview">
        <div class="article-photo">
          <img ng-src="{{$ctrl.article.image}}"/>
        </div>
        <h1 class="article-info">ARTICLE</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="article-content">
        <h1>{{$ctrl.article.title.toUpperCase()}}</h1>
      </div>
      <article-block ng-repeat="block in $ctrl.article.blocks" block="block"></article-block>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div flex="20">
  </div>
  </div>
</md-content>
```

I also want to determine block type to return a corresponding template, here is my block component:

```
import controller from './block.controller'
import venueBlock from './venue-block.html';
import imageBlock from './image-block.html';
import titleBlock from './title-block.html';
import contentBlock from './content-block.html';

let views = {venueBlock, imageBlock, titleBlock, contentBlock};

let articleBlockComponent = {
  bindings: {
    block: '<'
  },
  controller,
  template: function ($attrs) {// $attrs.block === 'block' it is a string, but not an object
    'ngInject';
    return views[$attrs.block.type + "Block"];
  }
};
export default articleBlockComponent;
```

Here is my controller:

```
class ArticleBlockController {
  constructor() {
    'ngInject';
    console.log(this.block);//undefined
  }
}
export default ArticleBlockController;
```

I've spent a lot of time trying to find a mistake, but I still don't see it.
I am quite newbie in Angular, and will be appreciate for help

Comment: Perhaps it's to do with how are passing the controller in the object. Does controller by itself work not throw an error? I would have thought that it would

Answer (score 1):

Component bindings doesn't get reflected inside controller context as soon as component controller initialised. You could get bindings attached inside `$onInit` lifecycle hook of component.

```
class ArticleBlockController {
  constructor() {
    'ngInject';
  }
  $onInit(){
    console.log(this.block);
  }
}
```

---

If you wanted work your component in that way then you have to tweak some setting in your `$compileProvider`, where you have to enable `preAssignBindingsEnabled`.

```
$compileProvider.preAssignBindingsEnabled(true);
```

> **Note**: Setting `preAssignBindingsEnabled` isn't preferred way that you should be doing in your
>   application. Basically it has been introduced to make Angular 1 component to looks same as that of Angular 2 component API. While migrating it will make your job much easier.

Comment: yes you are right, thank you, but how a can get an object property to determine which template I should use? I still have a problem with this cause I get string values in $attrs